# Noise removal where gains are >1

Tags: noise, power-spectral-density, denoising

I am currently working on some noise removal algorithms and have come across what seems to be an oversight in the design of some of these algorithms.

Two of the algorithms I am looking at use the PSD of the noisy input signal, and calculate the gains that should be applied to retrieve the noise-free signal.

However, both of these algorithms specify the gains should be $\in [0,1]$, with one (an autoencoder) specifying a sigmoid activation should be applied to its output to limit the gains between these values, and another mentioning the gains are $\in [0,1]$. In reality, however, the gains can be any positive integer.
Consider a signal $SN$ that is the sum of two signals $S$ and $N$, where $S$ is our noise-free signal and $N$ is our noise. Then, to calculate the (relative) PSD of these signals, we take the FFT of each, and square the absolute value. Now, given $\mathcal F\{x\}$ is the real FFT of $x$, and assuming our signals are real valued:

\begin{align}
SN &= S + N\\
\mathcal F\{SN\} &= \mathcal F\{S\} + \mathcal F\{N\}
\end{align}

However;

$$
\big(\mathcal F\{SN\}\big)^2 = \big(\mathcal F\{S\} + \mathcal F\{N\}\big)^2 \neq \big(\mathcal F\{S\}\big)^2 + \big(\mathcal F\{N\}\big)^2
$$

Therefore, there are some cases where our speech signal, for a given frequency, may have more power than our combined signal, hence our gains should be $> 1$.

- Why do the algorithms I have read assume gains should be $\in [0,1]$? Is this because we cannot be certain as to the nature of the input, and so letting the gains be $> 1$ could lead to much more disastrous artifacts?
- And if the noise we are removing is well modelled, does anything stop us from setting these gains to be greater than the combined signal?

Comment: thanks @Gilles for reformatting

Comment: You're welcome :)